# C# Libraries for pattern recognition in time series

Tags: c#, pattern-matching, time-series

Are there are any standard libraries for pattern recognitionin time series in c#? All I see are those in Python

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can check the following libraries :

1. [Cronos](http://cronos.codeplex.com/)
2. [Math.NET Iridium](http://mathnetiridium.codeplex.com/)
3. [Deedle: Exploratory data library for .NET](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/)

also you can call `R` functions from C# check [this link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25819/The-R-Statistical-Language-and-C-NET-Foundations)

Comment: Thanks for the reply!